# Activity called outside the tab

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

I am developing an app with 5 tabs and my last tab displays a list of menus. The problem appears when I click a menu tab, the menu activity appears nicely below my tab but when I click any of the menus (which it will call LoginActivity), the new Activity appears full screen not under the tab. How can I handle this? Below is my code.

**TabActivity**

```
package com.smartag.smarttreasure;
public class NfcSurveyActivity extends TabActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, mFilters,
                mTechLists);

        int profileCount = db.getContactsCount();
        if (profileCount <= 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        int profileCount = db.getContactsCount();
        if (profileCount <= 0) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            tabToDisplay = extras.getString("tab");
            if (tabToDisplay.equals("CAMERA")) {
                barcodeData = extras.getString("barcodeData");
            }
            extras.clear();
        }

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Home
        TabSpec tbspecHome = tabHost.newTabSpec("Home");
        tbspecHome.setIndicator("",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_account_style));

        Intent iHome = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        tbspecHome.setContent(iHome);
        tabHost.addTab(tbspecHome);

        // History
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Fun")
                .setIndicator("",
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_fun_style))
                .setContent(
                        new Intent(this, NfcSurveyActivity.class)
                                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));

        if (tabToDisplay != null && tabToDisplay.equals("REDEEM")) {
            if (barcodeData != null && barcodeData.length() > 0) {

                tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                        .newTabSpec("Camera")
                        .setIndicator(
                                "",
                                getResources().getDrawable(
                                        R.drawable.tab_redeem_style))
                        .setContent(
                                new Intent(this, NfcSurveyActivity.class)
                                        .addFlags(
                                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                                        .putExtra("autoLoadBarcodeData",
                                                barcodeData)));

            }

            else {
                tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                        .newTabSpec("Camera")
                        .setIndicator(
                                "",
                                getResources().getDrawable(
                                        R.drawable.tab_redeem_style))
                        .setContent(
                                new Intent(this, NfcSurveyActivity.class)
                                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));

            }

        } else {
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                    .newTabSpec("Camera")
                    .setIndicator(
                            "",
                            getResources().getDrawable(
                                    R.drawable.tab_redeem_style))
                    .setContent(
                            new Intent(this, NfcSurveyActivity.class)
                                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));
        }

        // tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);

        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = tabHost
                .getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height + 19;

        // Search
        TabSpec tbspecSearch = tabHost.newTabSpec("Finder");
        tbspecSearch.setIndicator("",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_finder_style));

        Intent iSearch = new Intent(this, NfcSurveyActivity.class);
        tbspecSearch.setContent(iSearch);
        tabHost.addTab(tbspecSearch);

        // Profile
        TabSpec tbspecProfile = tabHost.newTabSpec("Quit");
        tbspecProfile.setIndicator("",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_quit_style));

        Intent iProfile = new Intent(this, NfcSurveyActivity.class);
        tbspecProfile.setContent(iProfile);

        tabHost.addTab(tbspecProfile);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            tabHost.getTabWidget()
                    .getChildTabViewAt(i)
                    .setBackgroundColor(
                            getResources()
                                    .getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

            if (i == 2) {
                tabHost.getTabWidget()
                        .getChildTabViewAt(i)
                        .setPadding(
                                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i)
                                        .getPaddingLeft(),
                                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i)
                                        .getPaddingTop(),
                                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i)
                                        .getPaddingRight(), 20);
            }

        }

        if (tabToDisplay != null && tabToDisplay.length() > 0) {
            if (tabToDisplay.equals("CAMERA")) {
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);

            } else if (tabToDisplay.equals("HISTORY")) {
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

            }

        }

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                NfcSurveyConfiguration.SelectedTab = tabId;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**MenuActivity**

```
public class HomeActivity extends ListActivity {

    static final String[] Account = new String[] { "Point History", "Scan History",
            "Reward/Coupon History", "Share/Transfer History", "Personalise" };
    String tabToDisplay = "";
    String barcodeData = "";
    SharedPreferences nfcSurveyConfiguration;
    String profileId;

    String pleaseWait = "";
    protected boolean _taken;
    protected File _directory;
    protected String _filename;
    protected String _fileExtension;


    String profileName = "";
    String profileEmail = "";
    String profileStatus = "";
    String profileLanguage = "";
    String profileType = "";
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.listview_item_row, Account));

        ListView listView = getListView();

        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    //  ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1); // This activity appears not in the tab             
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        NfcSurveyConfiguration.CurrentActiveTab = 0;
    }

}
```

Any suggestion or advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code inside setOnItemClickListener help me to solve the problem.

```
View view1 = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(
                            "ReferenceName",
                            new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    YourActivityClass.class)
                                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                            .getDecorView();
                    setContentView(view1);
```